# Query not working and I can't see the error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to insert some data into my database but it doesn't work, I don't see the error, can someone help? `$by = $_SESSION['on']` is the user that's logged in.

Here is my source code.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title"><br>
<input type="text" name="content" placeholder="Content"><br>
<input type="date" name="date"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="send">
</form>

<?php
  include("databaseconnectie.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$content = $_POST['content'];
$by = $_SESSION['on'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO posts (content, date, by, title) VALUES(:content, :date, :by, :title)");
      $query->bindParam("content", $content);
      $query->bindParam("by", $by);
      $query->bindParam("title", $title);
      $query->bindParam("date", $date);
$query->execute();
echo "Trade Added";
echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: by/date are reserved words btw backtick-escape them.

Comment: It also should be `$query->bindParam(":content", $content);`. You really need to enable PDO to throw exceptions on error.

Comment: @AlexK. One is. One isn't.

Comment: ^ ...right, being the former and not the latter of what you said, as per documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html @AlexK. Edit: `date` being a "keyword" and not "reserved"; being two different animals ;-)